# How can i add dynamic list to enumeration to simpletype(dropdown) using XSD?

Tags: xsd

I have written dorp down element using simpleType restriction using XSD. here is my sample code.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="StatusListDropDown">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Submitted" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="In Process" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="Cancelled" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="Completed" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="Saved" />           
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

Actually my list size is more than 30 records and i don't want to hard code them in same XSD. is there any that i can get them dynamically. One idea is to have separate XSD for this list and import that using xsi:schemaLocation. is it correct way? or is there any good method to do this. please let me know. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly correct practice to take a frequently-changing enumeration like the one you describe and put it into a separate schema document which can be updated independently of the rest of the schema.  You ask for good methods to do this, but I think you have already found the best method.

One technical point:  unless you want to place the StatusListDropDown type in a separate namespace, you will want to use `xsd:include`, not `xsd:import` to bring it into the main schema document.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My requirement got changed and i will have strictly 10 records. So i placed them in the same xsd file. also thank you for correcting me on include part.